# Assign values to a dataframe by considering values in 2 columns of different dataframe as range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The following code explains the scenario,
I have a dataframe(df_ticker) with 3 columns

```
import pandas as pd 
df_ticker = pd.DataFrame({'Min_val': [22382.729,36919.205,46735.164,62247.61], 'Max_val': [36901.758,46716.06,62045.06,182727.05],
           'Ticker':['$','$$','$$$','$$$$']})
df_ticker`
```

[df_ticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9dy.png)
My second dataframe contains 2 columns

```
df_values = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'sal_val': [3098,45639.987,65487.4,56784.8,8,736455]})
df_values  `
```

[df_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmTTD.png)

For every value in df_values ['sal_val'], I want to check in which range it falls in df_ticker [Max_val] and df_ticker [min_val] and assign df_ticker [ticker] accordingly.
Sample output would be something like this, [sample_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y9Bq.png)
In the sample output, sal_val=3098 is greater than or equal to Min_val=22382.729 and less than or equal to max_val=36901.75, it was assigned ticker=$

I tried the following,

```
  df_values['ticker']=df_ticker.\
loc[((df_values['sal_val']>=df_ticker['Min_val'])| (df_values['sal_val']<=df_ticker['Max_val']))]['Ticker']
df_values
```

It failed with error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a custom mapping function and use `pd.Series.apply`.

```
def mapper(x, t):
    if x < t['Min_val'].min():
        index = 0
    elif x >= t['Max_val'].max():
        index = -1
    else:
        index = next((idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(t['Min_val'], t['Max_val']))\
                      if i <= x < j), None)

    return t['Ticker'].iloc[index] if index is not None else None

df_values['Ticker'] = df_values['sal_val'].apply(mapper, t=df_ticker)
```

**Result**

```
   Id     sal_val Ticker
0   1    3098.000      $
1   2   45639.987     $$
2   3   65487.400   $$$$
3   4   56784.800    $$$
4   5       8.000      $
5   6  736455.000   $$$$
```

**Explanation**

- `pd.Series.apply` accepts a custom mapping function as an input.
- The mapping function takes each entry in `sal_val` and compares it to values in `df_ticker` via an if / else structure.
- The first 2 `if` statements deal with minimum and maximum boundaries.
- The final `else` statement uses a generator, which cycles through each row in `df_ticker` and finds the index of values where the input is within the range of `Min_val` and `Max_val`.
- Finally, we use the index and feed it into `df_ticker['Ticker']` via `.iloc` integer accessor.

Comment: Your solution works fine.But, if I change one of the values in df_values to be same as min or max value in df_ticker, It returns None. Is there anything we can do to fix that? also it would be great if you could explain the logic.